# Use python selenium to open a YouTube Video

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I was trying to use Python selenium to write a script to open youtube and search a video then click some video of the search result. So far I was be able to finish the first 2 steps, but I am stack on how to click/open a youtube video after my search.
Right now my search method look likes this

```
......
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+'Covid-19')
```

After this, my script will open a youtube page with result relate to Covid-19, how should I open the first video of the search result?
I am new to python selenium, and I am trying to learn. Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a list of the elements of all videos:

```
videos = driver.find_elements_by_id('video-title')
```

For example if you want to click on the first video, you can simply do:

```
videos[0].click()
```

It will work regardless the search link you use.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, locate the first videos element by inspecting the page.
After locating the target element use this,
To click you can use this:

```
target.click()
```

Comment: Yea, I know that but this would not work if I change search key word to something else. I need something that works for all search key word. Thanks